# Voices disappear when using headphones

Tags: audio, headset, voice, c

How do I declare a variable in C?

**P.S.** I have a pair of SteelSeries Siberia headphones. I've noticed that when watching some films the voices are completely silent, yet when I unplug the headset and listen through my speakers they are there and sound normal.

I have no other software that could be interfering with it and it happens regardless of the software I use for playback (I've tried VLC, WMP and Quicktime).

It is so strange, and it almost sounds deliberate - the rest of the audio is untouched but voices disappear. The films only have single audio tracks, and it doesn't happen with every film.

Can anyone give me *any* hints as to what could possibly cause this? I am stumped!

Answer (score 3):

Have a closer look at the movies where the "voices disappear". Do they have DTS or other surround sound audio tracks? Maybe your Player doesn't downmix the 6 (?) channels to stereo (i assume the headphones are stereo?) and just discard every channel but two.

I had the same problem and noticed, that only the left-back and right-back channels were used. Voices usually come from the front channels.

btw.: This is not a programming question -> superuser.com

Comment: Thanks, it was the number of channels. Using VLC and selecting stereo audio instead of 5.1 worked.